# javascript alternative for jquery element addressing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

What is Javascript alternative for this:

```
$('#clientDetailModal #heightValue')
```

I need it because in my code this works:

```
document.getElementById('heightValue').checkValidity()
```

but this doesn't:

```
$('#clientDetailModal #heightValue').checkValidity()
```

And I need to select only heightValue within clientDetailModal div.

Comment: You should not use duplicate ID inside same document. Use a class and try a class selector. With that being said, you should probably tell us what `checkValidity` function is. Seems like it is exposed on DOM elements and not on jQuery object.

Comment: The ID identifier must be unique (only 1 per page), so if you do this: `$('#clientDetailModal #heightValue')` in jquery it's the same as doing this: `$('#heightValue')` but slower.

Comment: @tborychowski I don't know if OP edited (didn't see it at first) but question states *"I need to select only heightValue within clientDetailModal div"*.

Comment: @dystroy Aah, I see it. Thanks. Still - it's a bad practice and classes should be used instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `$('#clientDetailModal #heightValue')[0].checkValidity()`

The reason you need to do the `[0]` is, (as per the jquery id selector documentation)

> Calling jQuery() (or $()) with an id selector as its argument will
>   return a jQuery object containing a **collection** of either zero or one
>   DOM element

Since you'll get a **collection** with 1 DOM element (assuming you don't have multiple ids), you need to then explicitly "select" that element using the `[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the DOM element :

```
$('#clientDetailModal #heightValue').get(0).checkValidity()
```

Just to be sure, as your question might be a little ambiguous : only one element can have a given ID in HTML. So if your element is either absent or inside `#clientDetailModal`, then you could as well use

```
$('#heightValue').get(0).checkValidity()
```

It would also be faster. But in that case, there would be nothing wrong in using `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `document.getElementById('heightValue').checkValidity()` works, it means your function `checkValidity()` is attached on native DOM elements. This means, you can do:

```
$('#clientDetailModal #heightValue')[0].checkValidity()
```

**Plus**: If your HTML is valid with no duplicate IDs, you can simply do

```
$('#heightValue')[0].checkValidity()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP asked for a JavaScript alternative. On modern browsers,

```
document.querySelector ('#clientDetailModal #heightValue')
```

will return the element you are asking for.

The direct equivalent would be

```
document.querySelectorAll ('#clientDetailModal #heightValue')
```

which returns an array of elements matching the selector requested, do yrou will need to add the [0] as per the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

I presume this is what you're looking for :

```
document.getElementById('clientDetailModal').getElementById('heightValue').checkValidity();
```